Go-Back-N in RoCE: when does the senders waits for ACK?
In this paper explaining Go-Back-N algorithm in RoCE (RDMA over Ethernet protocol), that the sender is requesting an ACK not for every packet but for every X packets:

As for middle packets, sender will request the reply by a specific interval, such as 64/128.

Q1: Isn't it different than what this simulator does, which sends back an ACK for every single packet? Which one is the correct Go-Back-N algorithm?
In the same paper, they define the parameter ACK Timeout (in byte), which define the quantity of data to send before requesting an ACK.
They also show (eg. Figure 4c) that the sender will continue to send packets after having send a packet requesting an ACK. If packet n requests an ACK, the sender will continue to send packets n+1, n+2, etc...
Q2: When does the sender stops to send packets? Is it when requesting the second ACK, because maybe only one ACK can be outstanding at a time? Is this ACK interval the same parameter as the 64/128 interval, but expressed in bytes instead?
